# Using Angularjs to converting a string from node into a file download

Tags: angularjs, node.js, stream

I'm trying to take output from a node service call (a csv string) and feed it as a file stream so that it can be downloaded. I tried tackling this on the Node site with streams and pipes, but when I piped to stdout, my content went to the console, not back out to my caller. When I tried to return the stream from node, virtually nothing detectable happened. I've sort of come to the conclusion that what I'm trying to do should be done from the Angular side. I just need to take the output and feed it as a stream, just like this link does:

```
https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSEARCA:SPY&output=csv
```

It seems like a pretty straight-forward problem but it has me befuddled. Anyone have any thoughts on this?

V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from both the server and client side. From the server, you just have to inform the client what they data is and what to do with it:

```
function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/csv");    
    res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=my_data.csv")
    var data = "this,is,some,csv"
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
}
```

different combinations of content-types and dispositions will indicate to the browser what it should do with the data being sent:

```
"content-type":"disposition"
"text/text":"attachment" -> download
"text/text":"inline" -> display on screen
"text/csv":"attachment" -> download
"text/csv":"inline" -> download
```

as you can see with that last one, sometimes the client ignores your suggestion. It handles the media type `"text/csv"` as a download regardless of what you suggest it do. [Here's a list of the content-disposition options](http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml) and [Here's a list of media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

If you have some data that's been constructed on the client side and want the user to be able to download it:

You need to whitelist `blob` in the compileProvider. If you don't, the href will be prepended by "`unsafe:`". The default whitelist is http/https/ftp/mailto, so you need to append blob to the regex:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.config(function($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*https?|ftp|mailto|blob):/);
})
```

your controller:

```
var content = "this,is,some,csv";
var blob = new Blob([content], {type: "text/csv"});
$scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
```

your HTML:

```
<a download="text.csv" ng-href="{{url}}">download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this solution is that there is no file. I'm building a string in the Node service that I want to treat as a file on the client.

Comment: @VicF Just to make sure I have it straight before I edit it, you have a string `"hi, this, is, csv"`, and you want to send that as a downloadable file without saving it to a file on your side?

Comment: yep, that's about it.

Comment: @VicF I've updated my post. I'd recommend using the server-side approach.